# Primefaces component similar to p:messages

Tags: jsf, primefaces, components, message

Primefaces 5

Are there component  that shows data similar to `p:messages` component. I.e. greyed / colored box with close button, but without warning sign.

[image]

Or how can you use Messages component to show **any** content as panel component.

**EDIT**: If Message panel should be shown for several updates, as far as I know you must use FacesContext to add a message for every update. I don't want to do it.

**EDIT2**: This is what I want to achieve. At the best with a primefaces component.

[image]

As you can see:

1. any content
2. command link
3. close button

Comment: What else do you want to do with your Message? Where shall this message come from? If you just do not want to deal with the FacesContext on your own, consider using `Messages` from omnifaces...

Comment: There is `p:panel` component. Preferably I want to have such component, but with look of messages. I'm afraid there is no such component that looks like messages.Thanks for Omnifaces tip.

Comment: Then check the generated HTML output of `p:messages`. Basicly it is just a div-tag on which the css property `display` is set to `none`, when pushing the close-icon. This can be done easily either by plain JavaScript, or (like it is done in the p:messages) via jQuery.

Comment: Stg is right, what else do you want? Be able to close them etc? and with css you can hide the icon... easily

Comment: Thanks, but there is more... do you want it inline or more like a growl? Next to specific components? And just scan the PF showcase for things... Customizing the look of an overlayPanel comes closest I think

Comment: @Kukeltje yes overlayPanel is a good possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends if you want it to be inline or kind of 'popup'.

If you want it to not always be visibile, I'd use an [overlayPanel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/overlayPanel.xhtml) and with giving it a styleClass and some custom css it looks like what you want (styling done against default showcase theme):

```
.myCustomOverlay .ui-overlaypanel-content {
    background-color: lightpink;
    padding-right: 2em;
}

.myCustomOverlay .ui-overlaypanel-close.ui-state-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
    right: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

You can try this online with a browser developer tool

If you want it to be visible inline, I'd use a panel and style that in a similar fashion

```
.myPanel.ui-panel {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 lightpink;
}

.myPanel .ui-panel-titlebar.ui-widget-header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
}

.myPanel .ui-panel-titlebar-icon {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: medium none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: This looks good. I've tried your suggestion. As you asked it should be inline, like normal panel. And have a fixed postion, but possibly it's another question.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention it as you ask in comments.

Comment: Inline kind of contradicts fixed position. Panel is inline, growl is fixed position...

Comment: Yes, then inline. As normal `p:panel`. I'm not quite sure how to show `overlayPanel` as normal panel position. Not on mouse event but rendered always.

Comment: I just tried, and cannot get the overlayPanel to show inline by using some css. You have to revert to using the panel then and style that with some css. Similar to described above. I'll change my answer